# Filter magento Orders by From & To Date in custom page

Tags: orders, date, script

magento site : `www.1234.com`

we are displaying all the orders in page : `www.1234.com/php/site6/date.php` , user can able to see all orders only when user login to date.php page.

in date.php page,  we are displaying Order Id & Order Date & succesfully filtering orders based on entered order_id in textfield with help of below code.

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
{
    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app(); 
    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $accountType=$rows['type'];
    if($accountType=="admin"){

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('nin'=>'0'));

    }
    else
    {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'%'));
    }

    $i=0;
    foreach ($order as $orderData)  
    {

        $orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray=explode(",",$orderitems);
        $k=0;

        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while($k < count($orderitemsarray))
        {
            if($orderitemsarray[$k]!='0')
            {

                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(":designerorder_id"=>$orderData['entity_id']));

                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if($roworders['designerorder_id']==''){$dorderStatus="Unpaid";}else{$dorderStatus=$roworders['paid_status'];}

                $productdetail=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 

                $responce[]=array($orderData->getIncrementId(),$orderData->getIncrementId(),$orderitemsarray[$k],$productdetail->getName(),$designerName,$orderData['status'],$orderData['grand_total'],$orderData['customer_email'],$orderData['shipping_description'],$dorderStatus,$sDate);

            }
            $k++; $i++;
        }

    }       echo json_encode($responce);    

}
```

**html**

```
<select id="f_value2">
            <option value="entity_id">Order Id</option>             
        </select>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="doFilter()" value="" id="f_value1" >

<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" 
value="" name="post_at" />       
<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" 
value="" name="post_at_to_date" />

</form>
```

**script**

```
function doFilter() {
        var filterInfo=[
            {
                fieldName : $('select[id=f_value2]').val(),
                logic : "startWith",
                value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value1")
            },
            {
                fieldName : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_fieldName12"),
                logic : "greatEqual",
                value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value12")
            }
        ]
        var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid");
        var rowNOs=grid.applyFilter(filterInfo); 
    }
```

now we want to **filter orders by "From & To Date"**.

[image]

i am trying below php code [not js ] for filtering with From & TO date, i can able to display From & TO Date textfields with datepicker  , but when i click on search button its not working.

**php**

```
$post_at = '0000-00-00'; 
$post_at_todate = '0000-00-00';

$queryCondition = "";

    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) ) 
{           
    $post_at        = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) );
    $post_at_todate = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) )
    {
        $post_at_to_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) );
        $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
    }
    $queryCondition .= "WHERE DATE( created_at ) >= '" . $post_at . "' AND DATE( created_at ) <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";
//$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details where created_at >= '2016-11-17' AND created_at < = '2016-11-19'";
var_dump( $sqlquery );  




    $result = $conn->query($sqlquery);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $result->num_rows.'result found'."<br>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - date: " . $row["post_at"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results found <br>";
    }
$conn->close();
```

**Edit 2**

**I got that i am doing mistake that i am fetching Date table from magento db & trying to filter values using custom db, now please help me to filter values with help of magento db** [ as similar to filtering through entering order id in search box ] , for orders also i am using magento db only.

**custom db** : order_details

[image]

Comment: Have you getting post_at and post_at_to_date value in php file before sql query?

Comment: @Rakesh `var_dump($post_at);
var_dump($post_at_to_date);` result : `string(0) "" string(0) ""`

Comment: if you have not getting post_at and post_at_to_date then How filter works ?

Comment: @Rakesh okay , what i need to do to get solution ?

Comment: Where is doFilter() function in your js?

Comment: @Rakesh i am usign `doFilter()` function for displaying filters after entering order id in search box.... i am not using that for `From & To date`.....

Comment: But you have post_at_to_date used on input of doFilter(), i am not understand your point,

Comment: @Rakesh yes i tried that before , but it didt worked for me, so i am not using that now , instead i am using `<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" >`

Comment: I have updated based on magento way, query condition only for php part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
$queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at >= '" . $from_date . "' AND post_at <= '" . $to_date . "'";





$reg_user = new USER();
$stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details ".$queryCondition);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
```

updated code

```
$post_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; 
$post_at_todate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

$queryCondition = "";

    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) ) 
{           
    $post_at        = date( 'Y-m-d  h:i:s', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) );
    $post_at_todate = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) )
    {
        $post_at_to_date = date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) );
        $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
    }
    $queryCondition .= "WHERE  created_at  >= '" . $post_at . "' AND  created_at  <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";
//$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details where created_at >= '2016-11-17' AND created_at < = '2016-11-19'";
var_dump( $sqlquery );
```

Comment: Tried your code, `date picker` is not displaying.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento check the error log there is error on page? because query is not related to `date picker`

Comment: okay, i am trying now, i ll let you know exact problem soon......

Comment: for `from & To date` also i am trying the same javascript code that i used to filter orders through searching in textfield , looks like the code is not filtering : <input type="text" placeholder="To Date"   id="post_at_to_date"  value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" name="search[post_at_to_date]" onkeyup="doFilter()" value="" id="f_value1"/>

Comment: there are two value attribute in that `<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" name="search[post_at_to_date]" onkeyup="doFilter()" /> ` try now

Comment: tried, but didt worked, is i need to use different javascript code to filter orders based on Date ? because i am using `doFilter()` javascript code to filter orders based on entering order id in search box......

Comment: @BabyinMagento make sure you format is matched with database entry of date

Comment: i am using this : `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`, [same in database]  also now i am using `search` button to filter, but still not working, you can check updated code in question : `<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" >`

Comment: @BabyinMagento put condition in query too. updated the code check and feedback

Comment: sorry, still not displaying results once i click on `search` button....

Comment: please check `Edit 2` part in question....

Comment: `order_details` add this table structure and data so i can look at this

Comment: updated the question, but i dont think we need that `order_details` table here as dates are displaying from `sales_flat_order` table of magento db.....

Comment: update the code try n feedback...

Comment: result before click on search button: `string(28) "SELECT * FROM order_details "
5result found`  , result after click on search button : `string(126) "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE DATE( created_at ) >= '2016-11-01  12:00:00' AND DATE( created_at ) <= '2016-11-01 12:00:00'"
0 results found ` , you can check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date26.php) , un : kidsdial1@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial1 ,  [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date26.php)

Comment: updated the query test that..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time & patience, i got solution.....

Answer (score 2):

I have debug your code and found issue in **name** attribute.

> You have to just replace name="search[post_at]" with name="post_at"

And

> You have to just replace name="search[post_at_to_date]" with name="post_at_to_date"

in form input tag.

Also remove onkeyup() if you dont need.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test1";

echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";
$queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["post_at"])) 
    {           
        $post_at = date('Y-m-d 0:0:0',strtotime($_POST["post_at"]));
        $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d:59:59:59');
        if(!empty($_POST["post_at_to_date"])) {
            $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59',strtotime($_POST["post_at_to_date"]));
            $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
        }
        $queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at >= '" . $post_at . "' AND post_at <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
    }

    $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlquery);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $result->num_rows.'result found'."<br>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - date: " . $row["post_at"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results found <br>";
    }
$conn->close();
?>

<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" value="" name="post_at" />       
<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" value="" name="post_at_to_date" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Now after post form,

You have got value using,

**$_POST["post_at"] and $_POST["post_at_to_date"]** and create your query.

**Magento Way:**

```
<?php
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$tableName = $resource->getTableName('order_details');

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";
$queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["post_at"])) 
    {           
        $post_at = date('Y-m-d 0:0:0',strtotime($_POST["post_at"]));
        $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d:59:59:59');
        if(!empty($_POST["post_at_to_date"])) {
            $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59',strtotime($_POST["post_at_to_date"]));
            $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
        }
        $queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at >= '" . $post_at . "' AND post_at <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName. ' '.$queryCondition;
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: I truied , but still `var_dump($post_at);
var_dump($post_at_to_date);` results : `string(0) "" string(0) ""`

Comment: you have to try with $_POST["post_at"]  and $_POST["post_at_to_date"]  and change above form element. I have getting value for all those.

Comment: you are right, now `var_dump($_POST["post_at"]);
var_dump($_POST["post_at_to_date"] );` results `"2016-11-01" string(10) "2016-11-01"` , can you please help me to create query .....

Comment: what else i need to do for Filtering Dates based on `To & From Date`?

Comment: I have updated my working answer, please check above answer, which is based on filter of two date. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: whatever dates if we select than also , its showing all results.....

Comment: No only result show that are filter from those two dates of datepicker.

Comment: You have to change your db name and credential in above post. I have checked for filtering only.

Comment: i tried by giving correct db name & configuration, still its not filtering, still result : `0 results found `

Comment: you can check here once : [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date.php) un : kidsdial1@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial1 [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date.php)

Comment: please share your full code.

Comment: you can check full code here : http://pastebin.com/sh59w65M

Comment: please check `Edit 2` part in question....

Comment: You have to set $conn->query for magento way not php way.

Comment: if possible please give me  code to filter dates in magento way, [ i posted code about how i filtered  orders based on entering order id in search box.....]

Comment: i got this error : `Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/date27.php on line 93` , so i tried adding this code : `require_once '../../app/Mage.php';` , `Mage::app();` , now getting : `Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sbdev2.order_details' doesn't exist' in /var/www/html/sbdev2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228`

Comment: Have you created custom table name like order_details?

Comment: `order_details` is present in custom db , is i need to create that table in magento db ? , becuase we are fetching date from `created_at` column which is present in `sales_flat_order` table.....

Comment: ohh yes, you have to create those table in magento or you have to give query for sales_flat_order table instead of order_details.

Comment: okay i will replace `order_details `  text by `sales_flat_order`

Comment: when i click on `search` button , its giving error as `Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post_at' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/html/sbdev2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228`  , there is no column called `post_at` , but its not required right ?

Comment: yes you doesnot need post_at so you have to comment query conditions, Now only getting all row with same order id

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time & patience, i got solution.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for :

```
if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) 
{           
    $post_at = date('Y-m-d 0:0:0',strtotime($_POST["search"]["post_at"]));
    $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d:59:59:59');
    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"])) {
        $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59',strtotime($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"]));
        $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
    }

    $queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at BETWEEN '".$post_at."' AND '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, but still its not working, also i am not getting any errors also.

Comment: echo your query and try it directly in db. that will show you error if any. also change the dateformat of date picker and try like mm-dd-yy

Comment: I tried this : `echo $stmt;` , i got error : `Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string`

Comment: @BabyinMagento, echo 'SELECT * FROM order_details '.$queryCondition;
And try this query in your DB and check whats the error

Comment: i got this : `Notice: Undefined variable: queryCondition`

Comment: now i tried this code : `$queryCondition='';` now its displaying : `SELECT * FROM order_details`

Comment: @BabyinMagento, at line 105 try echo like. echo  $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";die; and check the query in DB

Comment: Thanks for helping me from long days,  Now its displayed `Array
(
)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time & patience, i got solution.....

Answer (score 1):

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
{
    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app(); 
    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 //  echo $_POST['post_at'];
   // echo $_POST['post_at_to_date'];
    $orderFromDate='';
    $orderToDate='';

    if(isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at']!='')
    {
        $orderFromDate=$_POST['post_at']." 59:59:59";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date']!='')
    {
        $orderToDate=$_POST['post_at_to_date']." 59:59:59";
    }
    $accountType=$rows['type'];
    if($accountType=="admin"){

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('nin'=>'0'));
        if($orderFromDate!='')$order->addFieldToFilter('created_at',array('gteq'=>$orderFromDate));
        if($orderToDate!='')$order->addFieldToFilter('created_at',array('lteq'=>$orderToDate));
        // echo $order->getSelect();
        //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('nin'=>'0'));

    }
    else
    {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'%'));
    }

    $i=0;
    foreach ($order as $orderData)  
    {

        $orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray=explode(",",$orderitems);
        $k=0;

        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while($k < count($orderitemsarray))
        {
           if($orderitemsarray[$k]!='0')
          {

            $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
            $stmtorders->execute(array(":designerorder_id"=>$orderData['entity_id']));
            $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($roworders['designerorder_id']==''){$dorderStatus="Unpaid";}else{$dorderStatus=$roworders['paid_status'];}

          $productdetail=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
          $designerName=getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID())." -(".$productdetail->getDesignerID().")";   
          $responce[]=array($orderData->getIncrementId(),$orderData->getIncrementId(),$orderitemsarray[$k],$productdetail->getName(),$designerName,$orderData['status'],$orderData['grand_total'],$orderData['customer_email'],$orderData['shipping_description'],$dorderStatus,$sDate);

         }
        $k++; $i++;
        }

    }       echo json_encode($responce);    


}
```

**script**

```
function doFilter() {
        var filterInfo=[
            {
                fieldName : $('select[id=f_value2]').val(),
                logic : "startWith",
                value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value1")
            },
            {
                fieldName : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_fieldName12"),
                logic : "greatEqual",
                value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value12")
            }
        ]
        var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid");
        var rowNOs=grid.applyFilter(filterInfo); 
    }
    function doUnfilter(){
        var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid1");
        var rowNOs=grid.unfilterGrid();

    }   


function doUnfilter(){
    var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid1");
    var rowNOs=grid.unfilterGrid();

}
```